# How do I call a theme function from Drush command?

Tags: drupal-8, drush

I would like to use a function defined in (active) custom theme (i.e. mytheme.theme) in a Drush command which is defined in a custom module, but it does not seem to be available and I cannot find a way to access it.

Can this be done, and how?

Comment: Put the function in a service and then inject the service into your custom command.

Comment: Indeed :-) I took the advice immediately, works like a charm and I do like the approach. You should have posted this as an answer.